# Internal Server Error: Laravel CentOs 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, centos, centos7

I have uploaded my Laravel Project on the Server which CentOs 7.
But after migrating the project i got the Error as shown in following screenshot:

[image]

I have Clear the Cache, also allow the permission to storage folder and update the composer and i have tried Many Stuff in order to solve but unfortunately none of them work form me.

Your Effort will be appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) `500 Internal Server Error server` error response code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

This error response is a generic "catch-all" response. Sometimes, server administrators log error responses like the 500 status code with more details about the request to prevent the error from happening again in the future.

1. You can have problem in your code that server can not parse it.
2. You should enable .htaccess by adding this to your vhost:

   Directory /var/www/html/yourfoldername

   ```
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```

Then  disable SELinux permanently:
https://www.tecmint.com/disable-selinux-temporarily-permanently-in-centos-rhel-fedora/

Answer (score 0):

Try to Fix 500 Internal Server Error: - change FollowSymLinks to SymLinksIfOwnerMatch in .htaccess files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).